# Help my Assassin Kill His Target

Tags: weapons, tactics, assassination, stealth

This normal looking man here is called Sam, and he’s about to kill a VERY important person whose death will bring about a great war. This would-be assassin is posing as an Alliance guard, face lift and everything. Sam and his extremist group (RED HAND) plan to kill the Commonwealth's president, and make it look like the Alliance did it (they are in cold war hostilities with each other). You are a tactician for the RED HAND; help guide Sam in picking the right weapon and the right plan. Go now comrade and bring the red death with you.

A major conference is being held in the demilitarized zone with all the most important officials going. The RED HAND with great loss of life and money got Sam a new face and ID as an Alliance security guard. Sam is ready and totally committed to the course. He is ready to die for the plan, but even better yet he is ready to kill for it.

**Layout Info:**

The conference will take place inside an old two story theatre. Both sides will have heavy security in place both outside and inside, but inside the theatre no one is allowed to carry guns, only stun batons. Sam has access to the building BUT will be checked for weapons by security when entering (both a metal detector and a pat down so carry light and NO metals). The target is protected by security at all times except when making a speech. Sam was the only operative from the RED HAND to make into the conference alive, so no back up and no helping HAND.

**Plan of engagement:**

Sam has false teeth with a hidden compartment inside (that could carry parts or ammo). Sam's belt and shoe heels also have hidden compartments that could carry small hidden items (a small poison coated plastic knife is inside the belt). Use of explosives or items that cause mass death is prohibited by the fact that like-minded people are attending who are needed to jump start the coming war (security guard deaths are clear). The RED HAND has booked out a VIP spot on the upper floor to have a safe place for Sam to put weapon parts together. The VIP spot has a view point over the conference hall can be used to shoot the target. The range is 15 meters from target (or get close and personal, death for Sam is the same anyway). Sam is skilled in both melee and marksmanship but he is no super-solder, so trying to kill every guard there is not going to end well but he can hold his own.

**Question:** What items would you bring and what will be your plan to take out the target?

I have my own ideas for Sam but I wanted a wider net for ideas on how Sam will kill the target. Any answers will be fine so long as you don’t jump the shark on weapons or tactics (modern items are allowed to be used).

Comment: WWI anyone? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Archduke_Franz_Ferdinand, the society was named the Black hand, serbia was in a cold war with austria-hungary...

Comment: Without knowing what will and won't pass security (which is a plot element we shouldn't be helping you with even if we could) we really can't begin to answer this question.

Comment: A poison injector inside a false tooth that activates when you bite someone would be pretty funny. Although, if he already has a poisoned knife in his belt, why would we need other weapons? Is access to the target a problem? Could he pretend to be a representative and go to shake the target's hand, only to bite him with his poisoned tooth, or would security not allow him to get that close?

Comment: The tough part of this question is how to make it look like "the Alliance" was behind the plot, as opposed to one radical security guard acting on his own.  Sam needs to engineer a situation in which he kills his victim in front of the cameras, with other Alliance guards appearing to be working with him.  Can he somehow provoke a fight between the two sides?

Comment: I think that just by conspicuously accomplishing the assassination while dressed as an Alliance member, he puts the Alliance in a difficult enough situation to cause division between Alliance and Commonwealth. Even if nobody notices him doing it immediately, as long as he does it in such a way that the investigation will trace back to him inevitably, it's mission accomplished.

Comment: I'm VTCing this as too story based.  The question is not a generic one which may apply in multiple situations, but one which will apply once, in one story, as long as you don't edit it to invalidate the solution.  That being said, it is missing the #1 single most important bit of information Sam can possibly have: who is at the event (including their guards), and what are their personalities?  Its generally accepted by pen-testers that people are the weak link, not buildings or computer systems.  Sam will almost certainly need to leverage the personality quriks of individuals to get past.

Comment: I’m VTC as too broad, since this question covers pretty much every weapon conceivable and a whole playbook of counterintelligence tactics, though it’s also primarily opinion based (how can we assess how good an answer is?) and story based (unless people causing cold wars to go hot is a regular occurrence in your world).

Comment: I'm VTCing as too story based.  Creed, please remember the primary purpose of this site is to help you build consistent rules for your world, not develop plot lines or scenarios within that world.  What world rule are you asking us to help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless his disguise is a plot element in itself, don't send Sam in as an Alliance security guard. The Alliance and the Commonwealth are in a cold war. If the Alliance were to assassinate the Commonwealth president, they would not send one of their own dressed in uniform. It would be implausible for both governments to be completely ignorant of the very existence of the Red Hand or some group like it. Cold wars are fought by spies, not soldiers. Each government will be focusing its efforts on gaining as much information about the other as possible. This would include any terrorist groups that may be a significant factor, such as the Red Hand.

If the Alliance *were* to attack the target, they would attempt to disguise the fact that it was their doing. They would set their entire intelligence force to the task.

## The Kill

My ideal plan for this mission is a two-man job. The first would be a triple agent. His first layer of cover would be as an Alliance spy on the Commonwealth. His second layer of cover would be a wish to defect to the Commonwealth, making him a double agent. He would, in fact, be truly reporting to the Red Hand, making him a triple agent. The goal is to convince the Commonwealth that the assassination was the Alliance's doing, meaning the staging here would be far more difficult than the actual kill. This spy's purpose would be to convince Commonwealth intelligence that the Alliance is behind whatever scenario you end up using for the president's assassination (or attempted assassination, should you intend for Sam to fail).

The second man of this two-man job would be your Sam, but I would not dress him as an Alliance guard. To come up with a good cover for him, you'd need to consider possible covers Alliance intelligence might give an agent sent to assassinate the Commonwealth president, or other people the Alliance might plausibly use for the hit. This will largely depend on the state of political affairs in your world, but ideas that come to mind:

- Commonwealth official who disagrees with the president on some major issue
- A mercenary hired by the Alliance to carry out the kill, complete with money trail.
- If the Red Hand were to spread information to the intelligence of both nations that the Red Hand is a terrorist organization sponsored by the opposing government, any action they take against one side would be perceived as an action by the other. In this scenario, Sam can be a poorly disguised Red Hand agent.
- Or Sam need never be caught. Have the Red Hand spread information through Commonwealth channels in the days preceding the conference that the Alliance is planning an assassination attempt on the president. Don't specify the timeframe, make it seem like it's a ways off so the Commonwealth isn't too cautious for this conference.

The actual carrying out of the kill is a less important matter. Assuming the president is giving some kind of speech, he would likely have a glass of water. I would have Sam utilize his master marksmanship and somehow propel a dissolvable pellet of some kind of deadly poison. I'm sure [the Internet](https://www.wired.com/2006/08/the-best-deadly-poisons-ingested-or-inhaled/) has a world of suggestions. The more the toxin makes you think "wow, a spy would totally use that to kill someone," the better it is for the job. When Sam shoots/tosses the poison down into the president's drink, assuming he's standing on the large stage and the guards aren't standing directly behind him, it will go unnoticed. If he does get caught, it should be because he needs to for the story to hold up that the kill was the Alliance's doing.

Comment: “disguise is a plot element in itself" well in fact it is, you see the Alliance and the Commonwealth were at war with each other 30 years ago. The alliance won the war and took some territory. The war itself was bloody and long. So the people from both nations hate each other not just from the war but there culture beliefs and governing structure. The RED HAND was founded by people of the Commonwealth under the rule of the Alliance. The RED HAND is supported by the Commonwealth in hopes of gaining independence. The RED HAND has been wiped out already by the Alliance Sam being the only one left

Comment: @CreedArcon So, to clarify, Sam is assassinating his own president, who his organization and fallen comrades were all supported by?

Comment: Sam is in fact a Alliance citizen that works for the RED HAND (but no known connection) so when he is killed it will look like Sam was set up to be working for the RED HAND (with the forged ID and face lift) but is from the Alliance that has already wiped out the RED HAND. the presidents death will let the vice president take over (who is a war hero and a bit more trigger happy) while the president was a bit more of a pacifist. so to sum it up. the  alliance will blame the Commonwealth for using the RED HAND. Commonwealth will blame the alliance for using an assassin from now dead group

Comment: @CreedArcon That’s pretty much what the point of my answer was, so good to know that’s what your doing! The question, which is apparently off-topic anyways, didn’t mention any of that context. Given the VP’s character, some mode of assassination that in some way humiliates the president or his country would probably rouse war even more.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- Bring and assemble a blow gun with plastic poison darts. The blow gun could also be hidden inside a hollowed out stun baton.
- Bring a small pouch full of hydrofluoric acid. Carefully empty the pouch onto the VIP's seat cushion when he's up making a speech. When he sits back down, the acid will sponge out of the seat onto his posterior. It is a contact poison and will kill him within 24 hours. Hydrofluoric acid has also been known to soak through people's shoes, so if you can generate a puddle and be sure that he'll step in it (or even just spill it on him somehow), that could also work. You could also empty the pouch into a water-balloon style pouch when you get there and toss it at him.
- Bring a small (pill-sized or coin-sized) ultrasonic weapon, bump into the guards and drop it in one of their breast pockets. The ultrasonic weapon is on a timer, and when active it emits a high-frequency noise which causes critical loss of brain function in a range. The immediate result is memory loss, fear, and mild hallucinations; after several weeks the victim falls into an coma.
- Bring an overvolted stun baton; it's like a grenade. If you want to be more destructive, you can also bring some shrink-wrapping and a bunch of ceramic shrapnel. Put the stun baton in the middle and fill the rest of the pouch with shrapnel, and now you have a much more ugly grenade.
- Bring a small trained bat, (he could hide the little guy in his pants or something) give it a poisoned ceramic razor and tell it to go dive on the VIP and cut him while he's giving his speech.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

He could shoot a poisened bolt from a crossbow. Have a look at this real [prison crossbow made out of toothbrushes](https://www.ranker.com/list/prison-weapons/mike-rothschild), that has a truly astonishing accuracy and range.

What you need:

- Some stiff, not bendable rod as the central stock. Sam could use a slightly modified baton, crutch, modified umbrella or similar object.
- Some elongated, flexible, but not too bendy objects as the bow. The example above shows how it's done with toothbrushes, but there are plenty of alternatives. Sam could hide specially manufactured parts in his baton, crutch or umbrella, he could use parts of the decoration inside the theater (wood, plastic or metal) or even fabricate some parts using 2-component synthetic material.
- The string. Any non-elastic rope would do. Sam could cut stripes from his trousers or belt.
- The release or lock mechanism. Here it gets complicated. Over centuries, men have developed several different types of locks that have different advantages or disadvantages. I think Sam would have to smuggle the lock into the theater as the chances of finding any improvised lock would be too slim.
- The bolt. Can be assembled from a metal pen and some fletching. There is modern fletching made from rubbery soft material with pre-glued double-sided tape. No problem for a professional assassin.
- The poison. Probably has to be smuggled into the theater, but copuld be applied to or transported in the ball pen refill. Bonus points for using a poison that is attributed to the Alliance. War is ensured!

During the preparations for the speach, he has enough time to assemple his crossbow and bolt. He could shoot his target like a sniper and create chaos before someone realizes where the projectile came from.